# Unable to fetch and show results of an API on microsoft botframework using nodejs

Tags: node.js, chatbot, botframework

I am trying to build a bot using microsoft bot framework and nodejs. I have a synchronous programming background and I'm trying to get a grip on nodejs.

While trying to execute an API using axios and give the results of the same API to the user I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
    at MainDialog.getSymptoms (C:\Windows\System32\botbuilder-samples\samples\javascript_nodejs\project1\dialogs\mainDialog.js:304:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

Code Snippet:

```
try{
            const response = await axios.get('https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics2.p.rapidapi.com/countriesData', {headers: {
                'x-rapidapi-key': '<key>',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-coronavirus-statistics2.p.rapidapi.com',
                useQueryString: true
              }});

           // console.log(response.data);
            info=response.data;            
            await context.sendActivity("These are the Symptoms: " + info);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
       // await context.sendActivity("Sorry, we were not able to complete your request.");
    }
```

This might be a very naive question, but please assist.

Edit 1: Referred and tried the below links, which didn't succeed --
https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/606
[Bot Framework V4 - TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969703/bot-framework-v4-typeerror-cannot-perform-get-on-a-proxy-that-has-been-revo) (tried with request module, axios etc)
https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/1957
https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/1856
[Bot framework - unexpected error when call turnContext.sendActivity method inside Cron callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382624/bot-framework-unexpected-error-when-call-turncontext-sendactivity-method-insid)
[use await inside callback (Microsoft Bot Framework v4 nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017732/use-await-inside-callback-microsoft-bot-framework-v4-nodejs)

The version I am using is microsoft-bot-framework-v4-nodejs

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52969703/1927991

Comment: @codemonkey tried the same, didn't succeed :(

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448881/cannot-perform-set-on-a-proxy-that-has-been-revoked & https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/1724